# An ODE with Hyperbolic function as solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, hypergeometric-function

Consider the following ODE,
$$
x \ddot{x} - \dot{x}^2 - 1 = 0.
$$
I can guess that the solution must be
$$
x = a \cosh \left(\frac{t - b}{a} \right)
$$
How to solve this ODE?

Comment: This isn't even a question.

Comment: My mistake. The question has been closed due to duplication though.